# Bug in org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream.available()?

Tags: java, netty

The ChannelBufferInputStream.available() method is:

```
@Override
public int available() throws IOException {
    return endIndex - buffer.readerIndex();
}
```

Wouldn't this break if you write to the buffer after the input stream has been initialized?

Shouldn't this actually be

```
return buffer.writerIndex() - buffer.readerIndex();
```

I am trying to do something like this:
Initialize the buffers and streams and read/write to the ChannelBuffer. What am I missing here?

```
final ChannelBuffer _channelBuffer = ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer();

final ChannelBufferOutputStream _outputStream = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(_channelBuffer);

final ChannelBufferInputStream _inputStream = new ChannelBufferInputStream(_channelBuffer);
```

Edit:
According to the constructor documentation of ChannelBufferedInputStream: "Creates a new stream which reads data from the specified buffer starting at the current readerIndex and ending at the current writerIndex."

In that case it makes sense. But is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do? Have a single backed buffer and the read operation waits for the write operation to complete.

Comment: I just spent a few hours trying to figure out why my input stream kept returning zero bytes available....now I know. I just pulled down a new build and I see no fix yet, maybe I'll pull down the source and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I need a stream to pull an AudioInputStream which unfortunately runs in a separate thread, but I found a work around by using a PipedInputStream / PipedOutputStream. Works great.

Basically, the messageReceived dumps my bytes into the PipedOutputStream, and my audio thread reads from the PipedInputStream and writes to my SourceDataLine.

Answer (score 0):

It's an intentional behavior.  The end of the stream is determined When a ChannelBufferInputStream is created.  I agree that the documentation did not state this behavior explicitly.  Let me fix it.

Comment: Thanks Trustin. Is there any other buffer/input stream that I can use to achieve this behavior. I want the read to block while the write (slow) operation fills the buffer.